# reopening all closed tabs which were accidentally closed

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

Many a times hundreds of tabs are open in my browser window and I accidentally press a button on top left-hand corner which I have encircled in the screenshot below.
I want to know is there a shortcut to open all those tabs in a single click or a key combination which have been accidentally closed by pressing this button.
The browser I am using is Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0.
The button with an arrow to left side in the screenshot is one which I am referring to.
[image: edge button screenshot]

Comment: What is it that you need,reopening the closed tab or removing the button encircled??

Comment: Re opening all those closed tabs which I accidentally closed by pressing that button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button doesn't close all the tabs, it sets them aside instead.

Look at these tabs opened up as an example and notice that this icon is blank/not filled white.
[image]

Now,after pressing the icon you mentioned,the icon beside it is filled in white.
 [image]

When you click that icon,this shows up.
[image]

This is where your tabs go.

Just click the <kbd>Restore tabs</kbd> option and your tabs will be back.

Answer (score 0):

If you accidentally clicked on the "Set these tabs aside" button in Microsoft Edge, you can easily restore those tabs by clicking on the "Restore tabs" option from the "Tabs you've set aside" panel, as highlighted in the screenshot below.

[image]